# incomplete result when using ThreadPoolExecutor of concurrent.futures

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, python-3.10

I got a strange behavior when running multi-thread of python program.

It's a very simple program to write 10 characters to a text file one by one, and I tried to do this with multi-thread.

```
from concurrent import futures

def print_one(character):
    with open('test.txt', 'a') as output:
        output.write(character + ' ')

def print_many():
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(3) as executor:
        executor.map(print_one, ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'])

if __name__=='__main__':
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as init:
        pass
    print_many()
```

The order of 10 output characters is random as expected, but sometimes I got only 9 like this:

```
1 2 3 5 4 6 7 9 10
```

You can notice that '8' is missing.

Maybe it is irrelevant, but this kind of results happened more often when I set max_workers of futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() to '3'.

So, there is no guarantee that ThreadPoolExecutor can start enough threads?

(or some threads just quit somehow without any exceptions or errors?)

Any advice would be appreciated.

(I am running this on Windows10 with python3.9.7-64bit)

**Update:**

I added try/catch and it seems there is no exception happened.

I put 100 results within a single run to a same file to find out how often this happens, and the result is about 2~3%.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as init:
        pass
    [print_many() for i in range(100)]
```

The results like this.

```
...
1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8 9 10 
1 3 4 5 6 7 9 8 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
...
```

**Update2**

I can't reproduce this on my macbook air(m1) with python3.10.

This is a windows only problem, maybe?

**Update3**

This happens on

Windows10 with python3.9.7-64bit(intel cpu)

Windows10 with python3.10.5-64bit(amd cpu)

**Update4**

Use threading.Lock() on file open can avoid this from happening but take a way long time.

Use global file(which means open file only once) can do this without time lose but characters are in quite same order from 1 to 10 so does not look like a multithread operation.(maybe it's just too fast?)

Comment: Try actually consuming the iterator returned by `executor.map`.

Comment: @yurikilochek Follow your advice I printed out the length of the iterator returned by map, it did returned 10 every time. But this is even more confused me that there were 10 threads indeed, but only 9 did their jobs?

Comment: Getting length might not be enough, iterate it to completion with e.g. `list(executor.map(...))`. I suspect that the executor is lazy in a sense that it isn't guaranteed to start all jobs at once, and will instead wait until the caller consumes the result of completed jobs before starting the rest.

Comment: @yurikilochek I modified the program with list(executor.map(...)) and nothing changed. But I did find that maybe the reason is not in concurrent.futures but in file open. I used file open in the print_one function, so the output file was opened/closed every single thread, and this may cause a time consuming operation AFTER thread throwing things to I/O stream. After I used a global file and only open it just once in whole run-time, then 10 characters were outputed every time. I am still working on how did this happen.

Answer (score 1):

After a little more digging in internet, I think I found what I need:

https://superfastpython.com/thread-safe-write-to-file-in-python/

The reason is not the concurrent.futures or the ThreadPoolExecutor, but the way python dealing with files.

Base on the above link, python's file open is NOT thread-safe, and the threading.Lock() in my **Update4** is one solution can avoid data lost.

Although I don't know why this only happened in Windows, it will be another question so I decided to close this question.